# Quarkus - support 2 types of jwt auth

Tags: jwt, quarkus, graalvm

Quarkus can support jwt auth by configuring the following properties in the application.properties file.

```
smallrye.jwt.path.groups=authorities
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=public.cert
```

in order to use it we just marking a given endpoint with the desired role:

```
@POST
@RolesAllowed("ROLE_TEST")
fun test(request: TestRequest): TestResponse
```

Is there an "easy" way configuring the app in order to support another type of jwt public.key.location like -

```
smallrye.jwt.path.groups=authorities
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=public.cert
smallrye.jwt.path.second=authorities
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location.second=second_public.cert
```

and if so, is there an easy way to differentiate between endpoints using the first jwt and other using the second one?
for example:

```
@POST
@RolesAllowed("ROLE_TEST")
fun test(request: TestRequest): TestResponse

@POST
@RolesAllowed("SECOND_JWT_ROLE_TEST")
fun test2(request: TestRequest2): TestResponse2
```

Comment: I've also opened https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/17945

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible with `quarkus-oidc` [multi-tenant](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-multitenancy) [service](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect) applications. A bearer token can still be accessed as `JsonWebToken` and `quarkus.oidc.<tenant>.roles.role-claim-path` can be used to point to a custom claim containing the roles/group information.

The multi-tenant idea is also being explored in the [MP JWT specification](http://%20https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-jwt-auth/issues/239). For now, if you prefer working with `quarkus-smalrye-jwt` then you can experiment with the [custom factories](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt#custom-factories) - here you'd inject `Vert.x RoutingContext` and manually parse the token based on the request path. Alternatively using [JWTParser](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt#create-jsonwebtoken-with-jwtparser) directly in the endpoint may also do in your case.